# Applications doesn't work after i removed everything in /var/snap and /var/log

Tags: partitioning, firefox, vlc, boot-partition

I have ubuntu 22.04 on my system and when i was installing ubuntu i did partitioning manually and i set just 4.6G for /var. But after a while i ran out of space in /var partition and i decided to clean up everything in /var/snap and /var/log but after that i still didn't have enough space and also icons of some of my softwares like Firefox, vlc and some other applications disappeared and by clicking on them non of them worked. Then i decided to increase /var space and i did it by booting ubuntu with usb and i increased /var size in gparted to 16G and then i reinstalled firefox and its icon is back but still it's not working. So if you had this experience before or you know what should i do please help me to fix it.

Also when i run `sudo firefox` in terminal i got this error:

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /snap/firefox/2880/usr/lib/firefox/libmozgtk.so:
libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM
```

Comment: Not sure what else you've expected. I would try to reinstall snap itself and all its packages.

Comment: @mikewhatever i tried to do that and i installed snap using ```sudo apt install snapd``` but when i run this command ```snap-store``` it gives me this error ```GLib-GIO g_app_info_get_name: assertion 'G_IS_APP_INFO (appinfo)' failed```